# EF Core ThenInclude after using AutoInclude

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query filter for the Event entity that uses the Project linked to that event, so I used the AutoInclude method to have it always available in the filter:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasQueryFilter(f => f.Project.OrganiserId == _userProvider.GetOrganizerId() || !_userProvider.GetAppRoleIsViewOnlyOwnEvents())
                .Navigation(d => d.Project)
                .AutoInclude(true);
```

My problem is that when I want to use `ThenInclude` to load some properties of a Project, these are not loaded:

```
    var eventEntity = await dbContext.DbSet<Event>()
        .Include(e => e.Project).ThenInclude(p => p.Organiser)
        .Include(e => e.Project).ThenInclude(p => p.Contact)
        .Include(e => e.Project).ThenInclude(p => p.Owner)
```

If I use `IgnoreAutoIncludes` then this works again, but this means I need to do this everywhere I want to include the project.

Is there any way I can solve this? I am using EF Core 5.

Comment: You do not need `Include` for query filter. `Include` only for loading related entities. So just remove `AutoInclude`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I do need the `Include` because I use the related Project from the Event

Comment: @OnurGelmez I'm not sure where should I try that

Comment: You need Include if you want to load related entity. For filter it is not needed!

Comment: @OnurGelmez the property are null, even though the ids are available

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv so, if I make a different query and I'm not including the Project, will the filter still be applied, even though it needs the related Project in order to check the condition?

Comment: @IonuțGabrielPițigoi did you try Svyatoslav Danyliv's answer. It can be your answer or if it doesn't work your EF model likely doesn't match what is in the database

Comment: For filter you do not need `Include`, believe me and just try. I'm very experienced in how LINQ translation works.

Comment: Yeah @SvyatoslavDanyliv you are right, it works without the `AutoInclude`. Thanks for the help!